# Are scalar/vector fields in multivariable calculus related to fields of vector spaces in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces

In linear algebra, I have learned that vector spaces are defined over fields. I have to admit that I don't have any background in abstract algebra, so my knowledge of fields are limited to $\mathbb R, \mathbb C$ etc.

In multivariable calculus, on the other hand, I have met with scalar and vector fields. It is said that scalar fields associate a number to every point, while vector fields are functions whose input is a point and whose output is a vector.

Are these two somehow related or is the term "field" generously used to describe two different things?

Comment: They aren't related, it's just the same word in English (French uses two different words for these concepts).

Comment: In Spanish they are also different words

Comment: Another example is "kernel".  The kernel of a homomorphism is the set of things mapped to the identity element, and in $\displaystyle (Tf)(y) = \int_D f(x) k(x,y)\,dx$, the function $k$ is a "kernel". No relation unless I'm going to be surprised. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I hope there are not many other examples. I really admire mathematics, but my reaction to such namings will always be a facepalm no matter how generally they are accepted by mathematicians.

Comment: @i.ozturk Unfortunately mathematicians tend to be horrible at naming things. Remember context is everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes in math, things are not named well. A vector field in $\Bbb R^2$ for example is a map $f:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$.  A field in the sense of a vector space over a field, is a set $S$ with both an addition operation and a multiplication operations where these operations satisfy some standard properties, such as commutativity (for addition), distributivity, associativity.  This is not a complete definition but it gives the idea.